# Subtracting each value in a row with the respective rowMedian using R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, apply

I have a matrix of 366*1055 dimension. I wanted to subtract each value (each row consists of 1055 elements) in a row with its respective rowMedian value. How to go about it ??

Answer (score 2):

Using the base package. The matrix m1 is from akrun's answer.

**Explanation**

We can use the `apply` function to apply a function, `median` in this case, to every row in the matrix m1. We set the second argument to 1 to indicate that the function will be applied over rows (row-by-row). The apply functions are very useful in R. For more details, type `?apply` in the console or check this thorough [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/2963704) by Joran.

```
m1 - apply(m1, 1, median)
```

**Output**

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]   -1    3   -3    0    1
 [2,]   -1    0    2   -1    0
 [3,]    1    0    1   -3   -4
 [4,]    3    4   -1   -1    0
 [5,]    3    0   -1    6   -3
 [6,]    3    3    0   -4   -6
 [7,]    0   -1   -2    5    1
 [8,]    2   -5    0    1   -2
 [9,]    2   -1    0    0   -4
[10,]    0   -1   -2    7    1
```

Comment: While this answer is correct, it would be worth adding some explanatory text so that later readers with less knowledge can understand WHY this is correct and how it works.

Comment: @kdopen You're right. I've just edited my answer to provide an explanation and a couple of references. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowMedians` from `matrixStats` to calculate the rowwise `median` and subtract it from the matrix 'm1'.

```
library(matrixStats)
m1 - rowMedians(m1, na.rm=TRUE)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
m1 <- matrix(sample(0:9, 10*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5)
```